# (Error) GlassFish: publishModule kind= 3 deltaKind=2 1 WebApp

Tags: java, eclipse, glassfish

I run Eclipse 1.6.0, and Glassfish V3 back end. The program run fine, the console give no error. However the error log always show this weird error. The application name is `WebApp`

```
 GlassFish: publishModule kind= 3  deltaKind=2 1 WebApp
 An exception stack trace is not available.
```

Here is the `Session Data`

```
 eclipse.buildId=unknown
 java.version=1.6.0_17
 java.vendor=Apple Inc.
 BootLoader constants: OS=macosx, ARCH=x86, WS=cocoa, NL=en_US
 Framework arguments:  -product org.eclipse.epp.package.jee.product -keyring /Users/KingdomHeart/.eclipse_keyring -showlocation
 Command-line arguments:  -os macosx -ws cocoa -arch x86 -product org.eclipse.epp.package.jee.product -keyring /Users/KingdomHeart/.eclipse_keyring -showlocation
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've got very similar traces in the Eclipse **Error Log** view as illustrated below (no exception stack trace available too):

[alt text http://img94.imageshack.us/img94/5618/screenshot004ug.png](http://img94.imageshack.us/img94/5618/screenshot004ug.png)

Nothing blocking though (I didn't notice this problem before you posted it). But there is something wrong somewhere and it should be reported as a bug of the Eclipse plugin: https://glassfishplugins.dev.java.net/issues/.

**Update:** I've created [Issue #311](https://glassfishplugins.dev.java.net/issues/show_bug.cgi?id=311). You can vote for it. (PS: You should really learn to do such elementary things. Just create an account and ask for the right to report issues, that's all).

**Update 2:** <strike>[Issue #311](https://glassfishplugins.dev.java.net/issues/show_bug.cgi?id=311)</strike> has been closed as invalid, nothing wrong with this trace. Stop worrying about it.

Comment: If you know how to report, then please do so. And let us know the solution to this bug. tyvm

Comment: @Harry I've created an issue (see my update). Feel free to upvote and accept my answer as a thanks :)